How to expand a Streamlit expander (st.expander)?
I have an issue where I am creating a dashboard from my research on commodity price forecasting implemented with a Folium map and charts. However, when I use the st.expander function from Streamlit, there is a significant empty space on both the right and left sides of the map I generate (as can be seen in the picture). How can I make the map larger so that there isn't such a wide space on the dashboard I am creating?

The code:
# Create Folium map
m = folium.Map(
    location=[-7.417745006891739, 109.22726059533683],
    zoom_start=13, width='100%', height='100%'
)
folium.Marker(
    [-7.417745006891739, 109.22726059533683],
    popup=popup_manis, 
    icon=folium.Icon(
        color='red',
        icon='location',
        prefix='fa-solid fa-shop'
    ),
    tooltip=str('Pasar Manis')
).add_to(m)

with st.expander("Find market on maps", expanded=True):
    st.subheader('Map')
    st_folium(m, width=675)

I actually just want to make the map bigger and neater, including tidying up the margins on both the right and left sides.

Can you post your code? Have you already set st.set_page_config(layout="wide")?

this is my code

```
# Create Folium map
m = folium.Map(location=[-7.417745006891739, 109.22726059533683], zoom_start=13, width='100%', height='100%')
folium.Marker([-7.417745006891739, 109.22726059533683], popup=popup_manis, icon=folium.Icon(color='red', icon='location', prefix='fa-solid fa-shop'), tooltip=str('Pasar Manis')).add_to(m)
popup=popup_m).add_to(m)

with st.expander("Find market on maps", expanded=True):
    st.subheader('Map')
    st_folium(m, width=675)
```

You can use set_page_config to specify a wide layout. However, every component will be adjusted, not just the expander.
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(
    layout="wide",
)

st.sidebar.date_input(
    "Select date", value=None, min_value=None, max_value=None, key=None
)

with st.expander("Find market on maps", expanded=True):
    st.subheader("Map")
    st.image("https://picsum.photos/500/500")

which gives:


Solved!!! thank's sirr
